# How to show results similar to countif in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm trying to count records in SQL Server and get the same results as I would in Excel by using Countif function.

I've tried Count(*) and other different ways of counting records in SQL Server but couldn't get the same results.

Is there a function or logic that would allow me to get results similar to the table shown below?

[image]

Comment: You use COUNT() and GROUP BY().  Best if you show your query so we can offer suggestions.  Otherwise, something like: `SELECT Fruits, count(*) as CountIf from dbo.table1 group by Fruits order by CountIf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with window function:

```
select Fruits, count(*) over(partition by Fruits) as Counts
from TableName
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgi. This answered by question.